# How a generic class to conform a protocol (that have init in it) with constraint?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Sorry for all these protocol mess. I provide it for the sake of code completeness. The question is actually about the last chunk of the code at the bottom.

```
protocol Edgedable: Hashable {
    associatedtype Edge: Destinationable
    var edges: Set<Edge> { get set }
}

protocol Destinationable: Hashable {
    associatedtype D: Hashable
    var destination: D { get set }
}

class Graph<Node: Edgedable>: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    typealias Edge = Node.Edge
    typealias D = Edge.D
    private var storage: [D: Node]
    
    init(_ tuples: [(D, Node)]) {
        self.storage = .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: tuples)
        // Some PostInit code here
    }

    required convenience init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (D, Node)...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }
}

extension Graph: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where D == Int {
    
    required convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: Node...) {
        self.init(Array(zip(0..., elements)))
    }
}
```

I choose a standard approach here: via extension. It looks like exactly what I need. That is the class implements the protocol only in the case of `D == Int`
But the code doesn't compile:

> 'required' initializer must be declared directly in class
> 'Graph' (not in an extension)
>
> Initializer requirement 'init(arrayLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by
> a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class
> 'Graph'

Okey, I can declare it directly in class, exactly like I did with another init (and another corresponding protocol). But how to set the constraint!?

```
class Graph<Node: Edgedable>: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral, ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where Node.Edge.D == Int {
```

This is not correct. This declaration has a different meaning. Not that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can replace `extension Graph: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where D == Int ` with `class IntGraph<Node: Edgedable>: Graph<Node>, ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where Node.Edge.D == Int` (new subclass type), don't forget to "open up" `designated init`.

Comment: It will probably solve the problem locally, but it will ruin the whole idea of one "generic" class for all purposes. I believe there is should be a way to deal with such a trivial problem without creating new highly specialised subclasses.

Comment: @Roman `init(_ tuples: [(D, Node)])` should definitely be private in your requirement?

Comment: @gcharita No, public is ok as well :) If it's public, problem is the same.

Comment: @Roman there is a solution but again includes the creation of 2 classes, one for `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` protocol and one for `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol. But both of them will subclass a `Graph` generic class. Is this something acceptable from you?

Comment: @gcharita I'm not sure yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to achieve this without making Graph `final`. If you do make it `final`, however, it will work fine as long as you remove `required` (`required` doesn't mean anything if there can't be subclasses):

```
extension Graph: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral where D == Int {
    convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: Node...) {
        self.init(Array(zip(0..., elements)))
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try this, but wouldn't making Graph a struct solve it too?

Comment: Also, sorry, but since I'm trying to document this stuff just now, what does "There's a new feature that allows extensions in the same file to be treated as part of the main definition" refer to? I mean e.g. in the release notes. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I would expect that this would also be fixed by a struct, though that would potentially change the semantics since it's mutable. It's difficult in my experience to create these kinds of data structures as structs in Swift (it's hard to even build a linked list…)

Comment: @matt I swear I saw a SE for this, but I cannot find it anywhere. It's possible the actual change is related (indirectly) to SE-267, but I can't find the SE that actually allows this to compile with Swift 5.3.

Comment: What version of Xcode 12 are you using? I copied and pasted the OP's code right into a project in Xcode 12 beta 5 and it did not compile.

Comment: @matt Wow…burned by Playground bugs again. In a Playground it shows "Succeeded" in the status bar, but the Playground actually fails to compile. I have got to stop falling for Playgrounds… Removed all nonsense from answer.

Comment: :) Repeat after me: "Playgrounds are the work of the devil...!" — Yeah, this leaves us with the `final` approach, which I think is the best one can hope for.